# How to import packages from custom .jar file in Zeppelin notebook on Azure HDInsight

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jar, apache-zeppelin, azure-hdinsight

I am following the documentation [here](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/latest/usage/interpreter/dependency_management.html):

Using a Zeppelin notebook on an Azure HDI 4.0 cluster, I would like to import packages from a custom .jar file.  I have placed a copy of the .jar file in the default storage account for the cluster, but I cannot figure out how to specify the correct path as a dependency.

[Trying to add the .jar file as a dependency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayKs6.png)

I have tried the following paths:

`wasbs://<container-name>@<account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/<path-to-jar-file.jar>`

`https://<account>.blob.core.windows.net/container/<path-to-jar-file.jar>`

In all cases I am told the path/file does not exist.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are passing the correct path of the custom jar.

There are several ways you can access the files in Data Lake Storage from an HDInsight cluster. The URI scheme provides unencrypted access (with the wasb: prefix) and SSL encrypted access (with wasbs). We recommend using wasbs wherever possible, even when accessing data that lives inside the same region in Azure.

**Using the fully qualified name:** With this approach, you provide the full path to the file that you want to access.

```
wasb://<containername>@<accountname>.blob.core.windows.net/<file.path>/
wasbs://<containername>@<accountname>.blob.core.windows.net/<file.path>/
```

**Using the shortened path format:** With this approach, you replace the path up to the cluster root with:

```
wasb:///<file.path>/
wasbs:///<file.path>/
```

**Using the relative path:** With this approach, you only provide the relative path to the file that you want to access.

```
/<file.path>/
```

**Data access example:**

```
Fully qualified path => wasbs://CONTAINERNAME@STORAGEACCOUNT.blob.core.windows.net/sampledata1/
Shortened path => wasbs:///sampledata2/
Relative path => /sampledata3/
```

For more details, refer "[Accessing files from Azure HDInsight Cluster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-use-blob-storage#access-files-from-the-cluster)".

Hope this helps. Do let us know if you any further queries.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just realized my file paths didn't show up properly in this post.  I have since edited.

I am using exactly those file paths, and copying them into the livy2 interpreter as a dependency (where it says "artifact").  But the response is always that the file doesn't exist.

The field indicates that I can use either `groupId:artifactId:version` or a local file path, but it isn't recognizing a file path on the default storage account for the cluster.